# BIRT Reports in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, report, birt

I'm learning BIRT Reports and implement in Spring Boot .When I try to implement  the BIRT Reports by adding it in my pom.xml as below,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.oda.jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i'm getting the error as
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

please any one help me
i need a solution

I use a IntelliJ, Spring Boot and BIRT Reports

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but AFAIK BIRT itself only uses plain java.util.logging. Maybe some data sources use SLF4J.

Anyway, this only means that without adding a SLF4J logging implementation, some parts of BIRT can not create log output. This has no impact on functionality, so you may ignore this message.